# Ruby on Rails 6 Postgres upsert_all differentiate between updates and inserts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm successfully updating some records using `upsert_all`, but now I'm working on a feature that should log the records that have been updated or created.

```
new_postcodes [{
  postcode: 'QBC123',
  created_at: Time.current,
  updated_at: Time.current,
}, {
  ...
}]

Postcode.upsert_all(new_postcodes, returning: ['postcode'], unique_by: :index_postcodes_on_postcode)
```

As far as I can tell `upsert_all` doesn't provide any details of what actually happened, and because I am also sending the `updated_at` date I can't differentiate between the records. Only idea I have would be to set a default value on the database field in Postgres, but I'd rather not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to make sure, that you know about PaperTrail gem, which could do that for you:

> Track changes to your models, for auditing or versioning. See how a model looked at any stage in its lifecycle, revert it to any version, or restore it after it has been destroyed